# Order a column based on an ordered column in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am having a data frame in R as follows:

```
structure(list(firstpurchaseMonth = c("January 2019", "January 2019", 
"January 2019", "January 2019", "January 2019", "January 2019", 
"February 2019", "February 2019", "February 2019", "February 2019", 
"February 2019", "March 2019", "March 2019", "March 2019", "March 2019", 
"April 2019", "April 2019", "April 2019", "May 2019", "May 2019", 
"June 2019"), purchaseMonth = c("April 2019", "February 2019", 
"January 2019", "June 2019", "March 2019", "May 2019", "April 2019", 
"February 2019", "June 2019", "March 2019", "May 2019", "April 2019", 
"June 2019", "March 2019", "May 2019", "April 2019", "June 2019", 
"May 2019", "June 2019", "May 2019", "June 2019"), monthlyRevenue = c(42455, 
65953, 559367, 5218, 29570, 56850, 20263, 502867, 2994, 31974, 
43023, 35512, 1873, 601097, 34865, 784367, 9246, 57395, 18594, 
1849594, 105371)), row.names = c(NA, -21L), class = "data.frame")
```

The column firstpurchaseMonth is ordered based on the vector `month`

```
month <- c("January 2019" , "February 2019",  "March 2019",  "April 2019",  "May 2019",  "June 2019", "July 2019")
monthlyRevenue <- monthlyRevenue[order(match(monthlyRevenue$firstpurchaseMonth, month)), ]
```

I need to order the `purchaseMonth` column based on the `month` where the order of `firstpurchaseMonth` remains the same.

For instance, with the purchaseMonth as January 2019, I need to order purchaseMonth from Jan to June. Similarly, for Feb, the order will be from Feb to June.

This is the output format of the data frame (Month name will be the same as provided in the month vector -- January 2019, February 2019 etc)

[image]

Can anyone provide a solution to achieve this?

Comment: I have added the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want this?

First convert two dates column into ordered factors based on your vector, month.

```
df$firstpurchaseMonth <- factor(df$firstpurchaseMonth, levels = month, ordered = T)
df$purchaseMonth <- factor(df$purchaseMonth, levels = month, ordered = T)
```

Thereafter just `dplyr::arrange` would work.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% arrange(firstpurchaseMonth, purchaseMonth)

   firstpurchaseMonth purchaseMonth monthlyRevenue
1        January 2019  January 2019         559367
2        January 2019 February 2019          65953
3        January 2019    March 2019          29570
4        January 2019    April 2019          42455
5        January 2019      May 2019          56850
6        January 2019     June 2019           5218
7       February 2019 February 2019         502867
8       February 2019    March 2019          31974
9       February 2019    April 2019          20263
10      February 2019      May 2019          43023
11      February 2019     June 2019           2994
12         March 2019    March 2019         601097
13         March 2019    April 2019          35512
14         March 2019      May 2019          34865
15         March 2019     June 2019           1873
16         April 2019    April 2019         784367
17         April 2019      May 2019          57395
18         April 2019     June 2019           9246
19           May 2019      May 2019        1849594
20           May 2019     June 2019          18594
21          June 2019     June 2019         105371
```

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the column values to date objects so that you don't have to manage an external vector `month`.

```
library(dplyr)

monthlyRevenue %>%
  mutate(across(c(firstpurchaseMonth, purchaseMonth), zoo::as.yearmon)) %>%
  arrange(firstpurchaseMonth, purchaseMonth)

#   firstpurchaseMonth purchaseMonth monthlyRevenue
#1            Jan 2019      Jan 2019         559367
#2            Jan 2019      Feb 2019          65953
#3            Jan 2019      Mar 2019          29570
#4            Jan 2019      Apr 2019          42455
#5            Jan 2019      May 2019          56850
#6            Jan 2019      Jun 2019           5218
#7            Feb 2019      Feb 2019         502867
#8            Feb 2019      Mar 2019          31974
#9            Feb 2019      Apr 2019          20263
#10           Feb 2019      May 2019          43023
#11           Feb 2019      Jun 2019           2994
#12           Mar 2019      Mar 2019         601097
#13           Mar 2019      Apr 2019          35512
#14           Mar 2019      May 2019          34865
#15           Mar 2019      Jun 2019           1873
#16           Apr 2019      Apr 2019         784367
#17           Apr 2019      May 2019          57395
#18           Apr 2019      Jun 2019           9246
#19           May 2019      May 2019        1849594
#20           May 2019      Jun 2019          18594
#21           Jun 2019      Jun 2019         105371
```